# Fixing "Error in Thrift HTTP response: 301" in Evernote JS-SDK

Tags: evernote, evernote-app-notebook

I am creating a a node REST API which will authenticate EVERNOTE with my app through Oauth as a third part client. I have passed every authentication stage ( oauthToken and oauthAccessToken) and even got authorization mail sent to the evernote's email i used to authenticate.

But when i'm supposed to be redirected back to my app (in this case get an array containing all notebooks) and have all the clients notebooks listed i'm getting **Error in Thrift HTTP response: 301** and this json response instead

[image: JSON RESPONSE]

this response isn't making sense at all. How do fix this

Answer (score 0):

As of 16 May 2022, the sample in the official `evernote-sdk-js` package is outdated.

The package.json lists an outdated version of the `evernote` dependency at `"evernote": "2.0.0-beta"` resulting in this error.

To resolve this error, simply change the dep to `"evernote": "^2.0.5"`, re-run npm/yarn install.

Worked for me after this and was able to list the notebooks.